# android Graphview graph starting from right side of viewport

Tags: android, android-graphview, linegraph

I am building an application in which a live graph is plotted from some random readings. I am using android Graphview library for plotting the data points by adding `compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.0'` to the build.gradel. Every thing is working fine but the data plot is beginning from right side of the graph instead of the left side of the graph. I have searched a lot but could not find any solution. Please check the code that I have used and give your valuable suggestions.

```
xSeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    ySeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    zSeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    xSeries.setColor(Color.parseColor("#abcdef"));
    ySeries.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    zSeries.setColor(Color.parseColor("#123456"));
    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
    viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setMinY(-12);
    viewport.setMaxY(12);
    graph.setRight(1000);
    viewport.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setMinX(0);
    viewport.setMaxX(1100);
    viewport.setScrollable(true);
    graph.addSeries(xSeries);
    graph.addSeries(ySeries);
    graph.addSeries(zSeries);
```

add some values to the series like this.

```
xSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(point,x), true, 50);
ySeries.appendData(new DataPoint(point,y), true, 50);
zSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(point,z), true, 50);
```

Also I would like to know how do I show the number of seconds in the x-axis?
Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Comment: not till now, currently not working on it...

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The method .appendData has the "ScrollToEnd" parameter set to true. Try setting it to false like this:

xSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(point,x), false, 50);

Comment: it does start from the right side but in the end, it doesn't scroll.